# Multiple dependent ? Dockerfiles building a LAMP container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a LAMP container and I have already built several containers: httpd 2.4.23, redis 3.0.7, mysql 5.6.30 by compiling them myself from source code downloaded archives. I have based all of these above on the debian container.

Now that I'm doing the php 5.6.20 container it complains that it does not know about apache and mysql.

Here is the Dockerfile for the php container:

```
FROM debian

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential;
RUN apt-get install -y cmake;
RUN apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev libjpeg-dev libpng12-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libbz2-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev libgd2-xpm-dev php5-imap libz-dev

WORKDIR /usr/bin/
COPY php-5.6.20.tar.gz /usr/bin/
RUN gzip -d php-5.6.20.tar.gz
RUN tar -xvf php-5.6.20.tar
RUN ln -s php-5.6.20 php

WORKDIR /usr/bin/php/
RUN ./configure \
  --prefix=/usr/bin/ \
  --with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apache/bin/apxs \
  --with-config-file-path=/usr/bin/php-5.6.20/ \
  --enable-libgcc \
  --with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql/mysql_config \
  --with-zlib-dir=/usr \
  --with-jpeg-dir=/usr \
  --with-png-dir=/usr \
  --with-gd \
  --enable-gd-native-ttf \
  --with-freetype-dir=/usr \
  --enable-ftp \
  --enable-xml \
  --enable-zip \
  --with-bz2 \
  --enable-wddx \
  --without-pear \
  --enable-mbstring \
  --with-curl

RUN make

RUN make install
```

I wonder if I should base it instead on: `FROM httpd:2.4.23`. But then I would need to base httpd on the mysql one, and / or on the redis one... I don't really like that setup.

I have also installed Docker Compose but I wonder if it could be helpful in my situation.

UPDATE: Here is the fully working Dockerfile

```
FROM debian

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential;
RUN apt-get install -y cmake;
RUN apt-get install -y openssl libssl-dev;
RUN apt-get install -y libpcre3 libpcre3-dev

WORKDIR /usr/bin/
COPY httpd-2.4.23.tar.gz /usr/bin/
RUN gzip -d httpd-2.4.23.tar.gz
RUN tar -xvf httpd-2.4.23.tar
RUN ln -s httpd-2.4.23 httpd
COPY apr-1.5.2.tar.gz /usr/bin/httpd/srclib/
COPY apr-util-1.5.4.tar.gz /usr/bin/httpd/srclib/
WORKDIR /usr/bin/httpd/srclib/
RUN gzip -d apr-1.5.2.tar.gz
RUN gzip -d apr-util-1.5.4.tar.gz
RUN tar -xvf apr-1.5.2.tar
RUN tar -xvf apr-util-1.5.4.tar
RUN ln -s apr-1.5.2 apr;
RUN ln -s apr-util-1.5.4 apr-util

WORKDIR /usr/bin/httpd/
RUN ./configure \
  --prefix=/usr/bin/apache \
  --enable-rewrite \
  --enable-deflate \
  --enable-ssl

RUN make

RUN make install

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libncurses-dev

COPY mysql-5.6.30.tar.gz /usr/bin/
WORKDIR /usr/bin/
RUN gzip -d mysql-5.6.30.tar.gz
RUN tar -xvf mysql-5.6.30.tar
RUN ln -s mysql-5.6.30 mysql

WORKDIR /usr/bin/mysql/
RUN mkdir install; mkdir install/data; mkdir install/var; mkdir install/etc; mkdir install/tmp

RUN cd /usr/bin/mysql/; cmake \
  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/bin/mysql/install \
  -DWITH_INNOBASE_STORAGE_ENGINE=1 \
  -DMYSQL_DATADIR=/usr/bin/mysql/install/data \
  -DDOWNLOAD_BOOST=1 \
  -DWITH_BOOST=/usr/bin/mysql/install/boost \
  -DMYSQL_UNIX_ADDR=/usr/bin/mysql/install/tmp/mysql.sock

RUN make

RUN make install

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev libjpeg-dev libpng12-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libbz2-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev libgd2-xpm-dev php5-imap libz-dev

WORKDIR /usr/bin/
COPY php-5.6.20.tar.gz /usr/bin/
RUN gzip -d php-5.6.20.tar.gz
RUN tar -xvf php-5.6.20.tar
RUN ln -s php-5.6.20 php

WORKDIR /usr/bin/php/
RUN ./configure \
  --prefix=/usr/bin/php \
  --with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apache/bin/apxs \
  --with-config-file-path=/usr/bin/php-5.6.20/ \
  --enable-libgcc \
  --with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql/install/bin/mysql_config \
  --with-zlib-dir=/usr \
  --with-jpeg-dir=/usr \
  --with-png-dir=/usr \
  --with-gd \
  --enable-gd-native-ttf \
  --with-freetype-dir=/usr \
  --enable-ftp \
  --enable-xml \
  --enable-zip \
  --with-bz2 \
  --enable-wddx \
  --without-pear \
  --enable-mbstring \
  --with-openssl
  --with-curl

RUN make

RUN make install

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/apache/bin/apachectl", "start", "-D FOREGROUND"]

EXPOSE 80

# Build the container: docker build -t stephaneeybert/httpd:2.4.23 .
# Run the container: docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:80:80 --name httpd stephaneeybert/httpd:2.4.23
# Check that the port is open: nmap -p 8081 localhost
```

Comment: What do you mean of "it complains that it does not know about apache and mysql", can you post the logs?

Comment: It makes sense that it does not know about apache and mysql because there two are not installed in the container. My question was on how to go about the container dependencies.

Comment: Here is the log output: `./configure: line 8417: /usr/bin/apache/bin/apxs: No such file or directory
configure: error: Aborting`

Comment: It is the `--with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apache/bin/apxs` in the configure command that requires apache. I wonder how to go in Docker with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need apache running in your container, you can install apache in your image with above Dockerfile, just as the same as you install the build-essential stuffs. Which means:

```
RUN apt-get install -y apache2
```

or similar command. If you also need the configure for this apache application, you can use `ADD` or `COPY` command to add your configure file from outside to inside of your container. More details can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#/add-or-copy).

If you need apache as an independent container, you can use docker-compse to achieve it. Start apache in another container, then use [depends_on](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/depends-on) to config the dependency between your containers. You may use [ports](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/ports) to change the port number of each container, so they can communicate between each other.

Comment: I'm still with my issue. I would like to compile and build the php server. As you can see its configure script makes use of some apache and mysql paths: `--with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apache/bin/apxs` and `--with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql/mysql_confi`But these paths do not exist in this php container. They each exist in their own container. I wonder how I can build php without these two paths, and still have a lamp install at the end of the day.

Comment: @Stephane When you say "their own container", does that means your mysql and apache are running in two independent containers but php 5.6.20 container running in another container? If so, you may need to consider to run all of them in a single container. Image each container as a VM or physical machine, can you run Apache, MySQL, php in three different machines but still get LAMP running? If you can do it via any special configuration, that configuration should apply to your container situation as well.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping to have three containers, one for MySQL and one for Apache and one for PHP. And no I cannot run these three on three different machines. I now realize I should have one container per service, which in my case should translate as one container for MySQL and one for Apache-PHP. Now I just need to see how I can build Apache-PHP without MySQL and still have it communicate with MySQL.

Comment: Now I wonder how I can have Apache-PHP communicate with MySQL as a service, simply by giving Apache-PHP the MySQL port number. In the Java world we use a connector that makes this possible.

Comment: I have now added in the Apache Dockerfile all instructions to build MySQL and PHP as well, so as to be able to give PHP the Apache runtime and the MySQL client library: `--with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apache/bin/apxs --with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql/mysql_config`